# Tengo un problema con el Logueo de una cuenta con Django. Esta misma la estoy logueando mediante Google

Tags: html, python, sql, django

Estoy teniendo un problema que sucedió repentinamente.
Estoy haciendo una web, en donde la gente puede loguearse con las cuentas propias de Google, mediante username y/o por e-mail.

El problema es que había logrado entrar con la cuenta, pero cuando loguee fuera de ella e intente nuevamente hacerlo (mediante Google), me dio este error:

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/login/
UNIQUE constraint failed: account_emailaddress.email
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
UNIQUE constraint failed: account_emailaddress.email
Exception Location: C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\MyDegrees\env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 328, in execute
Raised during:  allauth.account.views.LoginView
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\MyDegrees\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\Desktop\\MyDegrees',
 'C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\Desktop\\MyDegrees\\env',
 'C:\\Users\\Nicolas\\Desktop\\MyDegrees\\env\\Lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 04 May 2023 17:15:16 -0400

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Adjunto mi código:

profile.html

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <div class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
        <h2>User Profile</h2>
        <h3 class="text-secondary">Welcome! {{ user.username }}</h3>
        <hr>
        <p><strong>Username: </strong>{{ user.username }}</p>
        <p><strong>Name: </strong>{{ user.firstname }}</p>
        <p><strong>Lastname: </strong>{{ user.lastname }}</p>
        <p><strong>E-Mail: </strong>{{ user.email }}</p>
        <hr>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

---

settings.py

```python
"""
Django settings for MyDegrees project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-40vpzaz-18w)&j*w66&8229fo_x+t8z$yzqcr=ohmfrt%bb*b*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'main',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

    "crispy_forms",
    "crispy_bootstrap5",
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        },
        'OAUTH_PKCE_ENABLED': True,
    }
}

CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap5"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap5"

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MyDegrees.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MyDegrees.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'University.db',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Configuraciones adicionales de Django-Allauth

if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend"

#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'MI CONFIGURACIÓN DE CORREO'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS = True
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
```

---

No sé si es necesaria más información del código.
De igual modo, estoy atento a las respuestas.

Gracias!